# Need to replace the underscore with the space in the value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to replace the value with underscore into the space.

```
<find>
      <letter>A_B</letter>
   </find>
   <find>
      <letter>C_D</letter>
   </find>
```

XSL I'm using

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($findname, '_' , ' ')" />
```

Expected Output is to be

```
<find>
      <letter>A B</letter>
   </find>
   <find>
      <letter>C D</letter>
   </find>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right function in mind. What's not working?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="letter">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '_' , ' ')" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaiU